# Hyperledger fabric couchdb crash report

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am developing blockchain network on Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.
and using couchdb. 
Some day I am restarting couchdbs and Peers, then one of the couchdbs issued the crash report(below).

> [error]  -------- CRASH REPORT Process couch_index_server (<0.208.0>)
>   with 0 neighbors exited with reason:
>   {'EXIT',{{'EXIT',{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_replicator",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,403}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,378}]},{mem3_shards,for_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,54}]},{mem3_shards,local,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,156}]},{couch_index_server,handle_db_event,3,[{file,"src/couch_index_server.erl"},{line,281}]},{couch_event_listener_mfa,handle_event,3,[{file,"src/couch_event_..."},...]},...]}},...}}
>   at couch_event_listener:do_event/3(line:150) at
>   gen_server:terminate/7(line:826) <=
>   proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call:
>   {couch_index_server,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors:
>   [couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.195.0>], messages: [], links:
>   [<0.204.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running,
>   heap_size: 2586, stack_size: 27, reductions: 6714
>
> [error]  -------- Supervisor couch_secondary_services had child
>   index_server started with couch_index_server:start_link() at <0.208.0>
>   exit with reason
>   {'EXIT',{{'EXIT',{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_replicator",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,403}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,378}]},{mem3_shards,for_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,54}]},{mem3_shards,local,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,156}]},{couch_index_server,handle_db_event,3,[{file,"src/couch_index_server.erl"},{line,281}]},{couch_event_listener_mfa,handle_event,3,[{file,"src/couch_event_..."},...]},...]}},...}}
>   at couch_event_listener:do_event/3(line:150) in context
>   child_terminated

I don't know what it says.
(Probably, failed to start index_server)

Please, tell me why the crash report is issued and what it says.

Addtional information：

Peer's ledger data is persisted, but couchdb's data is not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Did your CouchDB actually fail (e.g  did you see an error/panic while using the fabric network)? This is a "normal" behavior from the CouchDB if certain global databases are not created at the very beginning and CouchdB has already started looking for these. Please [see this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/setup.html) for more details.